# Having issues with reshaping two arrays for regression

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having difficulty understanding what dimensions are wrong in my array that are causing it to not run a regression model properly.

Here is my code I've tried so far.

```
x = df_new[["Orig. X", "Orig. Y", "Orig Z", "x (Inches)", "y (Inches)", 
       "z (Inches)", "Volume (orig. units)"]]
y = df_new["runtime (min)"]

x, y = np.array(X), np.array(y)
print ('Fitting model...')
model = build_model()
x, y = make_regression(n_features=7, n_targets=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)
print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)
model.fit(x,y)
score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print('Score:', score)
```

What can I do with my x and y to make the regression model work smoothly?
Both x and y are 100 rows. X has 7 columns, and Y is of course only 1 column.

*EDIT: build_model() code below*

```
def build_model():
    ridge_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ('poly_feats', PolynomialFeatures()),
        ('ridge', RidgeTransformer())
    ])

    pred_union = FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[
            ('ridge', ridge_transformer),
            ('rand_forest', RandomForestTransformer()),
            ('knn', KNeighborsTransformer())
        ],
        n_jobs=2
    )

    model = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('pred_union', pred_union),
        ('lin_regr', LinearRegression())
    ])

    return model
```

EDIT: Traceback error below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-775526fc779a> in <module>
     25 print(x.shape)
     26 print(y.shape)
---> 27 model.fit(x,y)
     28 
     29 score = model.score(X_test, y_test)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    265         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    266         if self._final_estimator is not None:
--> 267             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
    268         return self
    269 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    456         n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
    457         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
--> 458                          y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
    459 
    460         if sample_weight is not None and np.atleast_1d(sample_weight).ndim > 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    754                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
    755                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
--> 756                     estimator=estimator)
    757     if multi_output:
    758         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    550                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    551                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 552                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    553 
    554         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[  28.51328986   15.04637032   93.37898607  -98.63740483  105.3785245
  -46.01294375 -110.93503958 -144.79637899  -59.35923549   62.36778776
  -88.85236254   93.0756314   101.64029368  218.01391173  101.26137798
   54.72891455 -133.71211185 -125.99472368   29.94269368   71.59822427
  212.59784734  -33.55787108  184.89287736 -232.48041924  135.26734855
  -12.12651132 -172.7038076   -97.8749558   314.46956576  146.3874269
  102.80820968   76.93644443   16.96718666  134.04031743 -102.1777084
 -253.68761765  180.2381539    85.20069473 -140.62502367   47.03879138
  156.93511131   67.7676657    -9.04138323  123.93189227  174.12355414
  -56.19912667   61.63232531    2.04173984   34.86750124   -5.96328448
 -126.81900755 -174.96317239  111.01260932  -22.89424944   15.59595122
  280.37346561 -101.39356531 -176.98811589   88.49720305  -39.27647122
  -25.98321465  -33.27364379  -60.42319159  -48.1694774   -32.0730914
  138.79010141  -11.27634536  -74.92271316  -86.59070448  118.17802672
   64.50120432  -28.88942322  177.00001615  -75.84108743  -58.35393161
 -144.03754366  274.49491635  116.30453855 -123.67954762  -30.89047884
  -23.5174034    -1.00726339   -1.88196999  166.40349424 -137.95350454
   71.25835091  -64.09838143  -31.63507257  133.10292084  -67.9354037
   63.85237459  142.25572131 -108.63072303   -5.7313783   -50.98668871
   59.25002692  -13.43424531  -17.82269722  -45.83104936 -148.90728362
    1.50193106   17.87438824   81.92662239  -83.19388204   86.83775258
  -46.85608104  -84.17690659  -94.8195309   -42.46441727   48.86628343
  -86.59104641   98.88486117   65.52270744  190.27987169   86.45217583
   31.46603065 -116.71038463 -117.22039948   55.95260753   60.34723681
  136.14328873  -66.13663513  170.37393394 -234.74000246  142.4215913
  -15.46199011 -143.03607653 -106.87052936  239.01861784  141.20861316
   42.36405844   70.85384876    2.41030437  125.38478863  -49.55470155
 -175.47492103  146.60430159   83.0396612  -117.86866863   22.03673312
  111.04275639   68.28721289  -30.41667672   92.39030512  156.57403451
  -39.37562231   79.81213791   -7.6069786    39.83725999   12.14887626
  -68.94858082 -142.67522236  115.35903901  -29.70325292   27.43727563
  197.58564756  -93.72749402 -129.75046815   46.87218775  -28.13066948
  -32.2957201   -32.28477183  -68.89313453  -45.34605254   12.35023878
   99.43077668   -4.66376816  -81.9798013   -52.13944475   89.84264889
   25.88417774  -63.57461905  192.73937579  -43.27281399  -36.70804327
 -140.76773381  242.04620261  115.63767405 -101.22487977  -62.77992477
  -44.18638662    2.16920856  -24.62620964  162.50686903 -127.07490443
   31.10421595  -57.55304524  -74.66626193  131.84190948  -73.94748475
   59.1205745   146.03675545 -109.33328323  -27.49279807   19.15473012
   62.80408203   33.36949411   -1.9273022   -51.49779114 -111.2861183
   34.06674269   18.05670255   46.43729984 -140.21078294   64.59153281
   11.74490721  -57.39114509 -114.55901385  -13.53130554  -13.82323384
   -0.49549397   53.19906766   90.57809032  151.70561796  122.69049054
   72.98809521 -154.14476693  -74.05733629   32.41234415   50.97790246
  116.93388344  -63.94235318  133.64933024 -139.94909392  109.72026197
   11.56169254 -138.87962453  -59.10262835  174.53934447  156.64912468
   65.03610007   76.4964515    22.04764677  115.84366991  -46.86259747
 -161.7681963   158.8401824     6.38833818 -105.66046837   30.75080677
  109.00053199   49.33338858  -13.05038717  111.00662647  122.23128993
  -40.06503916   71.0503438    -8.47825212   -3.03806969  -11.35250807
  -90.35772487  -86.08357992  131.31669463   -7.10243146   65.56581852
  177.63529127  -20.92617293 -161.7681963    55.26073005   30.13803328
   -8.53039856   -2.46567779  -73.25040534  -21.31245277  -34.32898768
   67.07418455   -5.87635605  -70.95576416  -78.20779048  111.04994216
   -4.35860823    6.44163718  141.88283904  -55.03298105  -59.06454078
  -56.6655874   152.89861136   88.89354733  -32.13338662   10.56350227
  -36.24515621   15.19991518   27.09160819  122.94643958  -99.11494519
   89.08121089  -50.14558081  -22.37651747  141.88283904  -39.79718785
   55.29960662  125.56984308  -74.99872018  -20.25735477  -42.91528289
   51.09138403   -8.37011402    6.79676896  -49.05931304 -117.99910408].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Why are you reshaping in the first place? What are the shapes of `x` and `y` before reshaping them?

Comment: The shape of your `x` and `y` are not consistent, they should be having the same number of rows. And also how can you `x` can have only 1 column?? you are subsetting 7 columns for X.

Comment: Can you print the shape of `x` and `y` immediately they are created and post the full traceback error?

Comment: can you post your entire code? i.e. your `build_model()` block? Need to understand what is happening there.

Comment: Why are you reshaping 7 columns into 2 columns in the step `x = np.reshape(x, (-1,2))`? I would _really really highly_ recommend you check the output of this step compared to your original data. Your rows and labels are no longer related at all at this point, unless I'm very much misunderstanding your code.

Comment: With the latest version of your code, please edit in the full traceback of the error you're receiving.

Comment: Updated above. @G.Anderson

Comment: So there's...a lot here I don't understand. I assume that the reason you're seeing the latest error is because the `y` output of your `make_regression` function is the wrong shape, which can be fixed with `y=y.reshape(-1,1)` before your `model.fit`. I do want to be clear, though: you've completely overwritten your original `x,y` from your dataframe with fake data from `make_regression`, I'm assuming to test your pipeline, correct?